# HttpClient 3.1 - Enable JavaScript to view the page content

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, httpclient

I have been trying to get a page content using HTTPClient 3.1 and after executing the get method, I'm getting "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content" in return content.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

public class FormsAndSupplyNextAgent
{
HttpClient httpClient = null;
GetMethod getMethod = null;
String contents, reDirURL, secondLevelLink, cri,requestVerToken;
int httpStatus;

public String getPageContent()
{
    getMethod = new GetMethod("http://someurl.com");
    httpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
    httpStatus = httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);//200
    contents = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();//JavaScript error
    getMethod.releaseConnection();
}
}
```

Few Things I have tried below:

--> I have tried changing the CookiePolicy to DEFAULT, IGNORE_COOKIES, and other available options but still no luck.
--> Hard coded the cookie/used Cookie class/Header class to set cookie

Could you please let me what other things I can try to get the proper content. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest to set the ``User-Agent`` header. At least I would use that value to determine if a browser supports javascript. But the real question is: Is the "Please enable JavaScript to view the page content" the real content of the retrieved page or does that text just appear somewhere in the html?

Comment: @f1sh, Thanks for the reply. Yes. I have tried setting the **User-Agent** but it didn't work.
`getMethod.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");`
I have tried setting all the request headers.

Comment: @f1sh, Below is the content I have received.
     <html><head>
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
     <meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
     <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page  content.</noscript>
      <APM_DO_NOT_TOUCH>
      <script language="javascript">

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: I found out that HTTPClient doesn't support JS. Hence I switched to selenium.